# how do I replace nonrepeating character through .Net regular expression

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string. I want to replace "d" with "dd", using Regex.Replace, but only if the d is not repeating.

For example, if the string is "m/d/yy", i want to change it to "m/dd/yy". However, if the string is "m/dd/yy", i want to keep it the same, and NOT change it to "m/dddd/yy".

How do I do this? I tried Reg.Replace(datePattern, "\bd\b", "dd"), but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: BTW -- you are aware that backslashes in strings have to be escaped in order to make it to the regex engine, right?

Comment: If you've got backslashes in your regex (or even if you haven't, it's good practice) use verbatim string literals by prefixing the string with an ampersand, e.g. @"(.)(?<!\1.)(?!\1)"

Comment: An ampersand looks more like `&` than `@` -- but yes, using `@"literal strings"` is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
(.)(?<!\1.)(?!\1)
```

literally means "character, not preceded nor followed by itself".

Comment: This answer address the question most directly, I wasn't sure if .NET regex support zero width assertions, but I looked it up and it does.

Comment: It should even work as `(?<!\1)(.)(?!\1)` - even though \1 is referenced before the capturing group. At least in .NET, Perl and Java, not in Python, JavaScript (and possibly others).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check that each `d` isn't preceded or followed by another:

```
Regex.Replace(datePattern, "(?<!d)d(?!d)", "dd")
```

For the particular example in your question, plain string replacement would be more straightforward than using a regular expression: `datePattern.Replace("/d/", "/dd/")`. I'm guessing that your actual requirements are more complex, hence the regex.

Comment: The difference between yours and mine is that yours finds a single 'd' while mine finds a single any character.  Dunno which suits OP's needs better.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are correct; although you may have escaped the characters incorrectly. Try:

```
Regex.Replace(datePattern, "\\bd\\b", "dd")
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for what you are trying to do:

```
Reg.Replace(datePattern, "/d/", "/dd/")
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple approach is something like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/(d|ddd)/");
string replacement = "/$1d/";
string updated = regex.Replace("m/d/yy", replacement);
string updated2 = regex.Replace("m/ddd/yy", replacement);
string notUpdated = regex.Replace("m/dd/yy", replacement);
string notUpdated2 = regex.Replace("m/dddd/yy", replacement);
```